# Azure SQL Database restore - The request timed out

Tags: azure-sql-database

I'm trying to restore a very small Azure SQL Database, but I keep getting "The request timed out" error. I have tried twice in the last 24 hours. I tried this on another account with a different database and it restored fine within a few minutes. I'm wondering if anyone else has seen this issue and if so what is the resolution?

Comment: Can you try PowerShell? https://github.com/twright-msft/azure-content/blob/master/articles/sql-database/sql-database-point-in-time-restore-tutorial-powershell.md

Comment: Maybe is just a portal issue ...

Comment: Thanks guys. It turned out to be Microsoft having latency issues on their end causing timeouts on SQL Server. It's just very frustrating when you have to pay them to help you with their problem. It took over 2 days before they fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

So, the reason caused the error "The request timed out"  is Microsoft having latency issues on their end on SQL Server.

You payed them to help you with their problem. It took over 2 days before they fixed the issue.

Maybe it's not a good experience and costs you extra. And fortunately, the issue was finally fixed.

Your case also reminds us if we encounter this kind of problem in the future, that's a way to ask help from Microsoft Azure.

So I post your comment as the answer, and others can reference it.

Comment: Thanks Leon! That is all true except I didn't pay me them. I actually Tweeted them, which is option on the Ticket part when creating an incident, and several hours later I checked the Monitor Log and there were 3 entries with the word "Incident". The description was to do with latency BUT then a couple hours later that disappeared from the Log and the Restore was successful.